# How to derive the solution for the advection-diffusion equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have an analytical solution to the 1D Advection-Diffusion equation

$$c(x,t) = Ae^{-4\pi k^2Dt}\text{sin}(2\pi k(x-Ut))$$

where the advection-diffusion equation is

$$\frac{\partial{c}}{\partial{t}} + U\frac{\partial{c}}{\partial{x}} = D \frac{\partial^2{c}}{\partial{x}^2}$$

I also have initial conditions

$$c(x,t=0) = A\sin(2\pi kx)$$

How do I derive the analytical solution as above?

Comment: Physical intuition immediately suggests a substitution $y = x- Ut$ to remove advection, followed by a separation of variables $c = f(t)g(y)$. An immediate separation also works, but takes more algebra to work with.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I used this substitution and I got to the step where $$\frac{\partial^2c}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2c}{\partial x \partial y}=0$$, but where do I from here? I integrated wrt to $y$ but I think I am doing something wrong as I can get a nice equation to the separate.

Comment: Something surely went wrong. After a substitution you should've arrived to the usual parabolic equation, $\frac{dc}{dt} = \frac{d^2c}{dy^2}$. Again, think physics.

Comment: Is it still meant to be partial derivatives? only that you have put straight derivatives so I was just wondering